# Bug in markdown rendering when only diffs are whitespace

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, markdown, diff

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1692104) suggested edit diff looks very wrong when showing the markdown. The rendered output diff is fine, though. It almost seems as though it has prioritsed matching one part of the text *including* the whitespace at the expense of matching much, much more of the text *excluding* the whitespace. Surely whitespace diffs should be de-prioritised?

Answer (score 1):

This looks as expected now after the change I describe [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247423/side-by-side-markdown-diff-chokes-on-simple-indentation-edit/258959#258959).