# Side-by-side markdown diff chokes on simple indentation edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, diff

I don't think this qualifies as a bug, exactly, but [revision 5 on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21266516/revisions) has a terrifying side-by-side markdown diff that made me think I messed something up, when all I did was highlight all the code and hit Ctrl+K.

[image]

The regular side-by-side diff looks fine, though.

I guess I'm mostly leaving this here as an example of a case where the markdown diff-er fails hard, in case this is in the pipeline for being looked at somewhere down the line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have just deployed a massive overhaul of the Markdown diff engine. Two of the major changes are 1) that cases like like yours now [look as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21266516/revisions):

[image: screenshot of the fixed diff]

and 2) the left and right side of the diff line up much better, making it a lot easier to see what was added and removed where. Example (from revision 2 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/69172/revisions)):

[image: comparison of pre- and post-fix diff]

(old on the left, new on the right; click for full size). You can see that it's not perfect (the part starting with *2. A "site cache"*,  while correct either way, is actually nicer in the old version), and no diff engine ever will, but I think it's a huge improvement.

Comment: What technology does StackOverflow use for storing and managing diff data? I need to make a wiki-like website (ASP.NET Core) and need to keep revision data, and am not sure what's the way to go.